# How can I create new link when user clicked in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

There are many links in my project (like a/a.pdf a/b.pdf) (a = folder, a.pdf = file).I want to create new link when user clicked the link. Old folder will be deleted from database(MySQL) and link will be updated to new link in database(MySQL).
(in PHP).

(I'm not native English speaker so I'm sorry for mistakes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Link</title>
<script>
function openLink() {
    // Create new random folder name
    var randomFileName = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    // Create new link
    var newFilePath = "books/" + randomFileName + "/a.pdf";
    // Update href
    document.getElementById("myLink").setAttribute("href", newFilePath);
    // Open in new tab
    window.open(newFilePath, '_blank');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="myLink" href="books/a/a.pdf" target="_blank" onclick="openLink()">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about your code isn't working as expected?

Comment: How are PHP or MySQL involved at all here?  What isn't working as expected in the code shown?  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: If you want to delete something from the server, you need to send a request to a PHP script, not just change the link on the client. You can use AJAX for this.

Comment: When I was click the link , link will be open in new tab and link will be update (I don't know how to do)
Links are coming from database , i've coded as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new link using the appendChild method as in the code below:

```
<script>
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.title = "my title text";
  a.href = "http://example.com";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
</script>
```